# Make MSBuild output file visible

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, code-generation

There's a way to make the output file from MSBuild become visible in project tree (Solution Explorer)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="MyTarget" BeforeTargets="BeforeCompile">
    <MyTask
      InputFiles="@(None)">
      <Output ItemName="Generated" TaskParameter="GeneratedCodeFiles" />
    </MyTaskTask>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="@(Generated)">
        <InProject>True</InProject>
        <Visible>True</Visible>
      </Compile>
      <FileWrites Include="@(Generated)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want make the output file from MSBuild display in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: Exactly. Display together with user created files.